# How to find all implementations of a certain interface?

Tags: java, reflection, implementation, classloader, detection

I want to make my program initialization a bit "smarter".

I have several classes which represent commands. All these classes are immutable (i.e. creating only one instance of each should be enough for the whole application). All these classes implement `Command` interface.

I think that the fact that some classes are placed in the same jar with a class with the main method (maybe even in 1 predefined package) and that these classes implement one known interface should give enough information to make it possible to automate creation of their instances.

How can I implement this feature? (Obviously, it's something tightly connected with reflection, and maybe, with java class loading mechanisms, but I'm not an expert in these fields).

---

I want to have something like this:

```
public static void init() {
   ...
   Map<String, Command> commands = Maps.newHashMap();
   for (Class clazz : findCommandImplementationsInThisJarFile()) {
        //some try/catch stuff is ommited
        Command command = clazz.newInstance();
        commands.put(command.getName(), command);
   }
   ...
}
```

How to implement the tricky method `findCommandImplementationsInThisJarFile()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need extcos:

`select(javaClasses()).from("your.package").returning(allAnnotatedWith(YourAnnotation.class))`

Also supports thoseImplementing and thoseExtending etc...

See: http://sourceforge.net/projects/extcos/

Spring also contains similar code for it's component scanning that is easily adapted.

Comment: Cool! I like it. It has necessary features, simple in usage, and (I almost sure) it'll be very interesting to investigate the implementation (because I don't know yet how to do the same things myself).